# Convert array of letters into their counts with Python

Tags: python, arrays, count

I have an array, for example
[A,A,A,B,B,C,A,A,D,D,D,B]

I want to count the entries and convert it to this
[3A,2B,1C,2A,3D,1B]

I have tried a load of if else type logic but I'm having issues. Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: You say you are having issues, what is the issue you are having? Do you have some starter code you could show so I could see how far you've gotten?

Comment: It turned into a mess of if else statements and I knew there would be a better way. I'm going to try some of the answers tomorrow. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a good use of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['A','A','A','B','B','C','A','A','D','D','D','B']

[f'{len(list(g))}{k}' for k, g in groupby(l)]
# ['3A', '2B', '1C', '2A', '3D', '1B']
```

Comment: `[list(g) for k,g in list(groupby(l))]`  gives empty lists and removing `list()` from `groupby(l)` works well why is that so?

Comment: @Bibhav the groups with groupby are all tied to a single iterator so calling `list(groupby(l))` uses up the iterator of the groups. This is explained in the docs with: "Because the source is shared, when the groupby() object is advanced, the previous group is no longer visible. So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list". This allows it to work efficiently with large iterators.

Comment: Thank you, this perfectly solved my needs. I tried to upvote but I need more reputation first, I will get on that!

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `list.count()` to get the number of times the first item appears then use `list.pop(list.index())` in a for loop to remove all occurences of the first item, do this in a while loop until `len(lst)` returns 0

```
out = []
while len(lst) > 0:
    s = lst[0]
    c = 0
    while len(lst) > 0:
        if lst[0] == s:
            c += 1
            lst.pop(0)
    out.append(f"{c}{s}")
```

Comment: Seems like this produces `['5A', '3B', '1C', '3D']` with the poster's input, but they want `[3A,2B,1C,2A,3D,1B]`.

Comment: @Mark thank you for the comment, I didn't read the question correctly I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to solve this problem.

```
letters = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'D', 'D']

previous_letter = letters[0]
counter = 1
res = list()
for i in range(1, len(letters)):
    current_letter = letters[i]
    if current_letter == previous_letter:
        counter += 1

    else:
        res.append(f"{counter}{current_letter}")
        previous_letter = letters[i]
        counter = 1

res.append(f"{counter}{previous_letter}")
print(res)
```

The trick is in checking a change of letters and keeping track of the count.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This is what I was trying but I was hoping for a simpler solution. I found one above.